# DataGridView for Linux and MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I want to use some GUI-object for output some table's information (this information is readonly). There are DataGrid and DataGridView in Windows Forms, but I can't find same GTK#'s analogue.
Can anyone tell me what MonoDevelop's and Gtk# analogue of DataGridView I can use?

Comment: are you done with node view? is it working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [node view tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/nodeview-tutorial/) should get you started on how to use it. AFAIK this is what is available for DataGridView in Windows Forms. This [little guide](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/tutorials/) might get you up to speed on MonoDevelop also. CHEERS!